# Kali Linux's NVIDIA driver install guide does not work

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, kali-linux

I'm trying to get my natively installed Kali Linux distro to detect my second monitor. I have two Samsung S20B300 monitors but its only picking up one of them. The one it is picking up is plugged in via DVI. The one that it is not is plugged in HDMI on the computer and DVI on the monitor (I have a HDMI-DVI adapter). I know the issue is not with the monitors themselves because my dual boot windows detects both monitors.

I figured the likely culprit was that I didn't have the proprietary NVIDIA drivers downloaded. So I followed [the official guide](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux) to installing them except when I got to the last step of calling glxinfo to see if it worked, I got the output

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
```

And have no idea why. Obviously something didn't work because my second monitor still is not being detected either. I'm running a custom PC with an Intel Core i5 4690K processor and NVIDIA GTX960 GPU

Comment: Which version of the proprietary drivers got installed from the distribution's repositories? Note it should be higher than (or equal to) `346.35` in order to support GTX 960.

Comment: Shouldn't apt-get install nvidia-kernel-dkms automatically get the latest version?

Comment: That will get the latest version of the package in your distribution's repositories, which does not need to match the latest driver version published by Nvidia.